# pandas - sort columns and group by a particular field

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of objects

```
[
   {
       "companyid": long,
       "parentid": long
       "score": long,
       ...
   }
]
```

The parentid is nothing but the cid of the parent company
Sample data will look something like this

```
cid    parentid score
1      10       1000  
2      10       100
3      10       1001  
10     10       20  
11     100      1000  
12     100      100  
100    100      200  
111    1000     10  
112    1000     100  
1000   100      2000
```

I need to sort the values based on the score, but i want to group the values by parentid
I tried this which didn't really fit my requirements, since it groups then sorts

```
df.groupby('headcompanyid').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('score'))
```

Sorting by score will give this result:

```
cid    parentid score
1000   100      2000 
3      10       1001  
1      10       1000  
11     100      1000  
100    100      200  
2      10       100
112    1000     100  
12     100      100  
10     10       20  
111    1000     10
```

Grouping by parentid on the sorted data (which is my end goal), should give this result

```
cid    parentid score
1000   100      2000 
11     100      1000    // since 100 is the parentid, it needs to be pushed up the in the result set
100    100      200     // if multiple records are pushed up, then sorting should be based on score
12     100      100  

3      10       1001     // 2nd group by is based on 10, since 1001 is the next highest score which  
1      10       1000     // doesn't belong to the 100 parentid group
2      10       100 
10     10       20 

112    1000     100  
111    1000     10
```

i am using pandas v0.24.2 and python 3.7 if it matters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(['parentid', 'score'], ascending=[False, False])
```

Output:

```
    cid parentid    score
8   112  1000        100
7   111  1000        10
9   1000 100         2000
4   11   100         1000
6   100  100         200
5   12   100         100
2   3    10          1001
0   1    10          1000
1   2    10          100
3   10   10          20
```